# Facebook application, how to check if inside Facebook canvas / standalone using PHP?

Tags: php, facebook

I want to develop a Facebook connect application that can operate both inside a Facebook canvas or standalone.

Can I check if the user is using Facebook canvas / not using the official Facebook PHP client library?

Thanks, Andree

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In case of a Canvas page, Facebook will pass the client's IP address in an additional HTTP header called `X-FB-USER-REMOTE-ADDR`.

http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/Your_callback_page_and_you

If it's set, you're on Facebook.

A hacker could also send this header, and that could result in unexpected behaviour from your app when outside Facebook.

Comment: Yes it would be trivial to "forge" a X-FB-USER-REMOTE-ADDR header. Any security implications would totally depend on the app though. Great suggestion though for this problem!

Comment: Facebook doesn't seem to be presenting me with this header. Is this still the case?

Comment: Also not receiving this header

Comment: The earlier mentioned header is long-gone. You will need to check either `HTTP_ORIGIN` or `HTTP_REFERER`.

Answer (score 0):

Check the `HTTP_REFERER` header. If the referrer is "apps.facebook.com", then its loading in Facebook canvas.

Comment: Sadly, HTTP_REFERRER will not always be the facebook domain, especially when navigating from one page to another from inside the canvas.

Comment: @JulianH.Lam You can store the state in session.